# A generic DFS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, graph, depth-first-search

I implemented a general function for a depth-first-search (DFS) using JavaScript with default arguments and functions that need to be provided in order for it to work.

This function is using `async` & `await`, but both can be removed to make it synchronous.

- Is the naming sensible?
- Are there missing pieces that would be useful for a general DFS?
- Any other improvements/suggestions/problems with this code?

```js
async function dfs(
  v         = null,         // vertex `v` for the DFS starting point
  visited   = (v) => false, // function: return true/false if `v` was visited
  visit     = (v) => {},    // function: mark v as visited
  edges     = (v) => [],    // function: return list of vertices reachable from `v`
  previsit  = (v) => {},    // callback called before visiting edges
  postvisit = (v) => {},    // callback called after visiting edges
) {
  await previsit(v)
  await visit(v)
  Promise.all(
    edges(v).map(async (w) => {
      if (!visited(w))
        return await dfs(w, visited, visit, edges, previsit, postvisit)
    })
  )
  await postvisit(v)
}

async function testDfs() {
  const graph = [ // basic adjacency list graph
    { 'id': 'r', 'edges': ['a','b','c'] },
    { 'id': 'a', 'edges': ['b'] },
    { 'id': 'c', 'edges': ['r', 'a'] },
    { 'id': 'b', 'edges': ['d'] },
    { 'id': 'd', 'edges': [] },
  ]
  const visited = [] // list of visited vertex ids
  await dfs(
    graph[0],
    v => visited.includes(v.id),
    v => visited.push(v.id),
    v => graph.filter(w => v['edges'].includes(w.id)),
    v => console.log(' pre', v.id),
    v => console.log('post', v.id)
  )
}

testDfs()
```

Comment: There are some  issues making this question borderline off topic. The test function `testDfs` awaits the call `dfs(` yet `dfs` will resolves before the search has completed. If any of the `awaits`, ie `visit`, `previsit`, `postvisit` are delayed then `dfs` will resolve after first vert and there is a good chance that some verts will be visited more than once. Also DFS searches trees, your example is RELIANT on the array `graph`, Can you provide an example using a tree?  BTW Worst case DFS is O(n), your use of array `visited` makes it O(n^2) where `n = verts + edges`

Comment: @Blindman67 thank you for the review. How does `dfs()` resolve before visiting all nodes? I don't seem to understand the use case you are describing. Regarding your "dfs is for trees-only" comment, that is simply not true. DFS doesn't search just trees, a tree is one type of graph, but there are many types of graphs and DFS searches any graph by visiting all of its vertices - works just fine with cyclic graphs as well (which are not trees).

Comment: The early return is very dependent on JS context state and the state of `graph`.(You dont await promise all, and `edges(v).map(async (w) => {if (!visited(w)` is wrong as `!visited(w)` is not async). Semantics (tree/tree like/graph) A DFS searches by following edges and avoids (does not touch) unreachable verts. The callback in the example you provide `edges` touches every vert every iteration. Can you provide example that follows edges.